# Is there a way to hide commands by a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a realm with a few of my friends and i want to play the creeper primed sound at him but i am afraid he will see the command and ignore it

Im using: /playsound minecraft:entity.creeper.primed block

Version: 1.14.2

Comment: Does it have to be by a specific player or just command output in general?

Answer (score 2):

**Only operators can see command output from players.**

If the victim of the prank is an operator (has access to cheat commands), they will see an output message. If you demote them to a regular player, they will not see it in the chat.

If for any reason you cannot or don't want to demote a player, you can give yourself a command block, set the `commandBlockOutput` gamerule to false:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

And now, if you run your command through the command block, no one will be able to see the output in chat. However, the `/give` and `/gamerule` commands you did will still be visible in chat.

Answer (score 1):

Using this command nobody should be able to see what commands were used. The effect starts imidiately, so nobody will see that you used this command.

```
/gamerule sendCommandFeedback false
```

You can turn it back on with:

```
/gamerule sendCommandFeedback true
```

Players will be able to see when you set that gamerule to true, but by then you will already have completed your prank.

There may be some users with higher permissions that can still see command feedback, so make sure that your friend is not the server owner, or something like that (They would have to use server side mods though)